# Rails: Inserting into a table that does not have any model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I am new to rails.

I have three tables A, B and C where the relation is C belongs to A through B. Now I want to insert into B a new entry to establish one more relation between A and C. But the problem is that the model for B is not created in the project I am working on. The table B is created by putting the create table command for B into the create table migration file for table C. The structure of table b is (id, A_id, C_id).

```
create_table :C do |t|
    t.string :name
end

create_table :B do |t|
    t.belongs_to :A
    t.belongs_to :C
end
```

So I am stuck as to how to construct the mapping into table B. One way I thought about is to create the mapping between A and C by inserting the ids of corresponding records into table B. But as the model of B doesn't exist so I am not able to do so.

Can someone plz explain or point out to the appropriate resource?

Comment: can you explain this line "So I am stuck as to how to construct insert the mapping into table B. The table B is created by putting the create table command for B into the create table migration file for table C"

Comment: Why don't you create the model class for `B`? That's what models are _for_, to enable access to database tables.

Comment: @GaganGupta tried to improve the question. Can u plz check once more?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In the last, I will do that only if I don't find any other method. I just want to know if its possible without doing that.

Comment: How are your model relationships defined then, I wonder?

Comment: So, you're saying Table B is there but the Model for Table B doesn't exists.

Comment: @GaganGupta yup

Comment: Okay, try creating a file name b.rb inside model folder and create a class inside it as `class B < ActiveRecord::Base`. Try accessing it from rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the similar problem. In my case push did the trick.

For an example: Let say we have two table Doctors and Shifts and those are connected using doctors_shift. So if you want to add Shifts for a doctor, you can just use

```
Doctor.find_by(id:doctor_id).shifts.push(instance_of_shift_you_want_to_add)
```

, where for instance_of_shift_you_want_to_add you may basically use Shift.find_by(id:shift_id)